# If statement in tryCatch method not working

Tags: node.js, express, try-catch

I tried to set up an if statement in the try function to check if there were no users found. But instead of showing me the 404 error as specified, it shows the 500 error instead. Help please

This is the code I used down below

```
app.get("/users", async(req, res)=>{
        try {
            const users = await User.find({})
    
            if(!users){
                return res.status(404).send("No users found")
            }
            res.status(200).send(users)
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }
    })
```

Comment: have you tried to log `error` in catch and see what error you get?

Comment: @1sina1  yes i did, the code completely ignores the if statement and sends back the error in catch

Comment: then you might have error in `User.find`, what error you get in `try-catch`?